# MySQL impossible suspicious connections

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mysql, windows-server-2016, service

I have a MySQL Community service binded locally to "bind-address=127.0.0.1", bind that suppose no expose it to the internet.

I can't connect externally. However i'm receiving constantly on the log this kind of errors:

```
[Server] IP address '194.**.16.73' could not be resolved: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. 

[Server] Host name 'hos*<probabily a malicious site>*nnet.biz' could not be resolved: No such host is known.
```

With a lot of addreses supicious (including TOR exit points).

I see this thread [Suspicious Connections to My Database x.x.x.x Could Not Be Resolved](https://serverfault.com/questions/605230/suspicious-connections-to-my-database-x-x-x-x-could-not-be-resolved)

But didn't respond the main question:

1. How is possible that kind of requests without internet access?
2. What does fire this? Ok i understand, server want to nslookup it, but, what are trying from that hosts? It's dangerous?

If someone can bring ligth to my life I will be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the log file that contains these errors? Can you provide a bigger snippet of the log file?

Comment: Hello. Is Error log of MySQL Community Server  8 and all entries are the same. With repeated and another hosts.

Comment: Please tell what is the path for this log file.

Comment: I found the problem. Reply on  my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

Solution for help someone in the future:

The problem is MySQL since idk what version opens antoher tcp listener for Plugin X. Has to bind it locally too.